# Response Time Accuracy

Tags: python, time, python-3.4, psychopy

I am going to program a response time experiment in Python 3.4 with Pygame and PIL. Will Python's builtin time functions be accurate enough for a millisecond level accuracy of response times? Is PyParallel necessary, or is it necessary only for EEG or eye-tracking experiments?

Comment: IIRC, `time.time` just invokes the OS' timing functionality. So... Depends on how accurate your operating system is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's time functions are not the limiting factor here. Depending on your particular computer and OS, you can get microsecond resolution (subject to all sorts of caveats about multitasking and so on).

***The real issue is hardware.*** There is no point worrying about millisecond time resolution if you are collecting responses on a USB keyboard for example, with an indeterminate lag and variability. You need to specify your hardware setup, and if millisecond timing is a requirement, then you will need to do hardware-based validation of the timing performance.

You also need to specify the requirements of your particular task. A lot of the poor hardware resolution goes away if you have many trials to average over. And the influence of constant lags disappears (even if the lag is unknown) if you are comparing response changes across conditions rather than being interested in the absolute reaction time.

Answer (score 0):

The computer can track time much more accurately than necessary for this task. The following prints the time in seconds that I took to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after calling the function.

```
>>> import time
>>> def timing():
...     t = time.perf_counter()
...     input('go!')
...     print(time.perf_counter()-t)
...
>>> timing()
go!
0.09541451768191678
```

As long as you're not doing any weird blocking stuff while waiting for the user's input, the built-in timing functions should be more than adequate.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'weird timing stuff'?

Comment: "Weird __blocking__ stuff" - any resource-intensive process that blocks further execution of the program until it's finished.